# Multirows, multicolums and vertical centring in the tabu environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow, tabu

I have a table, using the `tabu` environment, in which I would like multirow and multicolumn cells. Inside the cells, any content that doesn't vertically fill the cell should be vertically centred.

However, I can't seem to get it to behave sensibly - everything looks slightly jumbled and uncomfortable and some text spills over the cell boundaries.

I have tried to use `X[-1,m]` for every column in the column descriptor, without success.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Recommendations for treatment }

        \begin{tabu} {X[-1]|X[-1]|X[-1]|X}
            \hline
            T1 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{N0}  & Radiotherapy or surgery to the primary tumour.\\
            \cline{2-4}
            & N+ & $ <2{cm}$ & Radiotherapy or surgery to the primary tumour and neck.\\
            \cline{3-4}
            &  & $ >2{cm}$ & Radiotherapy or surgery to the primary tumour. Surgery to neck.\\
            \cline{1-4}
            T2 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{N0}  &  \multirow{3}{*}{\vbox{Radiotherapy or surgery to the primary tumour and neck.}}\\
            \cline{2-3}
            & N+ & $ <2{cm}$ & \\
            \cline{3-4}
            &  & $ >2{cm}$ & Surgery to the primary tumour and neck.\\
            \cline{1-4}
            T3 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{N0}  & \multirow{3}{*}{\vbox{Radiotherapy or surgery to the primary tumour and neck.}}\\
            \cline{2-3}
            & N+ & $ <2{cm}$ & \\
            \cline{3-4}
            &  & $ >2{cm}$ & Surgery to the primary tumour and neck. Postoperative radiotherapy in selected cases.\\
            \cline{1-4}
            T4 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{N0} & \multirow{3}{*}{\vbox{Surgery to the primary tumour and neck with planned postoperative radiotherapy to primary site, and to neck if indicated.}}\\
            \cline{2-3}
            & N+ & $ <2 {cm}$ & \\
            & & $>2 {cm}$ &\\
            \hline
        \end{tabu}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result is:

[image: Result of the above code]

What is the "right" way to achieve this kind of result in `tabu` enviroments? Or should I be using a different environment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility; instead of `tabu` I used the [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package; I set the last column to be `\RaggedRight` from the [`ragged2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package; to improve the vertical spacing I also redefined `\arraystretch`. For some of the cells, the second optional argument of `\multirow` was used to fine tune the position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Recommendations for treatment}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {l|l|l|>{\RaggedRight}X}
            \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}[-1ex]{T1} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{N0}  & Radiotherapy or surgery to the primary tumour.\\
            \cline{2-4}
            & \multirow{3}{*}[-1ex]{N+} & $ <2{cm}$ & Radiotherapy or surgery to the primary tumour and neck.\\
            \cline{3-4}
            &  & $ >2{cm}$ & Radiotherapy or surgery to the primary tumour. Surgery to neck.\\
            \cline{1-4}
            \multirow{3}{*}[-2ex]{T2} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{N0}  &  \multirow{2}{*}{\vbox{Radiotherapy or surgery to the primary tumour and neck.}}\\
            \cline{2-3}
            & \multirow{2}{*}{N+} & $ <2{cm}$ & \\
            \cline{3-4}
            &  & $ >2{cm}$ & Surgery to the primary tumour and neck.\\
            \cline{1-4}
            \multirow{4}{*}[-2ex]{T3} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{N0}  & \multirow{2}{*}{\vbox{Radiotherapy or surgery to the primary tumour and neck.}}\\
            \cline{2-3}
            & \multirow{3}{*}{N+} & $ <2{cm}$ & \\
            \cline{3-4}
            &  & $ >2{cm}$ & Surgery to the primary tumour and neck. Postoperative radiotherapy in selected cases.\\
            \cline{1-4}
            \multirow{3}{*}[-2ex]{T4} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{N0} & \multirow{3}{*}{\vbox{Surgery to the primary tumour and neck with planned postoperative radiotherapy to primary site, and to neck if indicated.}}\\
            \cline{2-3}
            & \multirow{2}{*}{N+} & $ <2 {cm}$ & \\
            & & $>2 {cm}$ &\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Is there any way to vertically centrally align the "T1" and "N+" cells as well?

Comment: @Inductiveload yes. Please see my updated answer.